# Cron job failing silently after update to 5.45.2

Tags: joomla, upgrade, cron-job

We upgraded to CiviCRM 5.45.2 on Joomla 3.10.5 and everything was working fine until we attempted to send a mailing to about 1000 recipients. The cron job started failing silently after that, with no notification to us or a visible notification in the dashboard. I contacted our host and they are seeing a 500 error in the Apache access log, but no corresponding entry in the Apache error log, so they said it is coming from either Civi or Joomla.

Example error below:

```
192.xxx.xxx.xx - - [31/Jan/2022:13:58:35 -0500] "GET /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=[redacted]&pass=[redacted] HTTP/1.1" 200 5628 "-" "lwp-request/6.36 libwww-perl/6.36" 0 0 "on:TLSv1.3:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" 895 3404768 192.252.151.10 www.[redacted].com proxy:unix:/home/[redacted]/.config/php-fpm/.sockets/php-fpm-ZrxRl01wU0Jb5N0KjTcmWLbh8.sock|fcgi://ZrxRl01wU0Jb5N0KjTcmWLbh8 - 192.xxx.xxx.xx
```

We've never had a similar issue prior to the upgrade, and the only error notices I received were about updating system templates. Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Comment: Can you send the mailing using 'Execute now' on the scheduled job? That would help figure out whether it is the cron side of things failing, or the mail sending.

Comment: I did try that and it did not work - but I did get a resolution from our host so I'll post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our host helped resolve the issue. The cron job was failing silently by timing out. We had to lower the amount of emails triggered per run and updated the cron to have a longer period before timing out. Our host also increased the number of resources available for running cron jobs.